# Execute the SSIS package from C#

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to execute the SSIS package based on user intervention rather than scheduled time.

I know these two approaches

- Using Application(from .net) to call Package( Can either call the package directly or can Call the job which has been already scheduled or create new job and start the job based on need basis )
- Using Stored Procedure to call Package

Please share your inputs on which one would be the best way and kind justification please

Comment: this show several ways with some benefits/drawbacks (maybe a bit outdated) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the various approaches, most involve using `xp_cmdshell` or `sp_startjob`. This could be problematic due to the user's security privileges, or in the case or `xp_cmdshell`, the stored procedure being disabled all together.

At the bottom of the blog post cited by @stb is a promising approach using [PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/10/11/remote-ssis-package-execution-with-powershell-2-0.aspx).